# Mysql insert query in after a chosen row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have persons in my database with their attended trainings but as time goes by, each of them will add some trainings again so i need to add it after that name.

I have table with columns id, firstname and training but that's my problem, inserting after a selected name

Sample

```
Insert into table (firstname, training) values ("Zarie", "Technical Writing Course") after a selected row where id = (select id where firstname="Zarie");
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can get result in `order by` which you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you adding row to mysql table it goes to the end of table or on free primary key id. You can't change this when you inserting data. You can change order only when you selecting data:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'name' ORDER BY id DESC, firstname ASC
SELECT id, firstname FROM table WHERE name != 'Zimbo' ORDER BY firstname ASC
```